# How to set view frame on full screen(include nav bar and status bar)?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar, navigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` with `UICollectionView`. How can I set collection view (and his cells) frame on full screen include nav bar and status bar height? (programmatically)

Comment: from storyboard?

Comment: programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You just must assign `UICollectionView` to superView not to safeArea. But you will have UI problems on the iPhones with screens as iPhone X

Comment: Can you please write some example or more explain?